# How to sum specifc levels from a dataframe vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame with three situations, where two represent met and one unmet. I need to add column n based on the levels (partially met and fully met) of the situation column. I could create a new column based on a condition and generate two levels, met, and unmet, but I don't think it's necessary.

This is my first try which doesn't work:

```
SITUATION <- rep(c("UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET"),8)
BLOCK <- rep( 1:8, each = 3, len = 24 )

TOTAL <- floor(runif(24, min=2, max=32))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(SITUATION, BLOCK, TOTAL))

agg_df <- aggregate(df$TOTAL, by=list(grepl(c("FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET"),
                    df$ATENDENCE)), FUN=sum)
```

> ```
> Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
> arguments must have the same length    
> In addition: Warning message:
> In grepl(c("FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET"), df$ATENDENCE) :
> argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

[image]

Comment: When you do this: ```df <- as.data.frame(cbind(SITUATION, BLOCK, TOTAL))``` your `TOTAL` column is converted to characters. Although that's not the only issue with your code. I showed the proper way of using "processed" values from a column within `aggregate` in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input Data:

```r
set.seed(123)
SITUATION <- rep(c("UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET"),8)
BLOCK <- rep( 1:8, each = 3, len = 24 )
TOTAL <- floor(runif(24, min=2, max=32))

df <- data.frame(SITUATION, BLOCK, TOTAL)
```

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(TOTAL ~SITUATION+BLOCK, 
          data = within(df, SITUATION <- ifelse(grepl("UNMET", SITUATION),
                                                "UNMET", "MET")), 
          sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% 
  mutate(SITUATION = ifelse(grepl("UNMET", SITUATION), "UNMET", "MET")) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .by = c(SITUATION, BLOCK))
```

Output:

```
#>    SITUATION BLOCK TOTAL
#> 1      UNMET     1    10
#> 2        MET     1    39
#> 3      UNMET     2    28
#> 4        MET     2    33
#> 5      UNMET     3    17
#> 6        MET     3    46
#> 7      UNMET     4    15
#> 8        MET     4    45
#> 9      UNMET     5    22
#> 10       MET     5    24
#> 11     UNMET     6    28
#> 12       MET     6    12
#> 13     UNMET     7    11
#> 14       MET     7    58
#> 15     UNMET     8    22
#> 16       MET     8    52
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, you don't know how much you helped me. I spent the whole morning trying and you quickly solved my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

Create `factor` with negation of `"UNMET"`.

```
with(df, aggregate(list(TOTAL=TOTAL), 
                   list(SITUATION=factor(SITUATION != "UNMET", labels=c('UNMET', 'MET')), 
                        BLOCK=BLOCK), sum))
#    SITUATION BLOCK TOTAL
# 1      UNMET     1    12
# 2        MET     1    39
# 3      UNMET     2    12
# 4        MET     2    44
# 5      UNMET     3    27
# 6        MET     3    38
# 7      UNMET     4    30
# 8        MET     4    38
# 9      UNMET     5    13
# 10       MET     5    35
# 11     UNMET     6     8
# 12       MET     6    28
# 13     UNMET     7     9
# 14       MET     7    15
# 15     UNMET     8     3
# 16       MET     8    49
```

You found a weird way to create your data frame, though, which produces characters from numbers. If it's really like your example, `type.convert` it beforehand.

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is=TRUE)
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(SITUATION = c("UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", 
"UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", "UNMET", "FULLY MET", 
"PARTIALLY MET", "UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", "UNMET", 
"FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", "UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", 
"UNMET", "FULLY MET", "PARTIALLY MET", "UNMET", "FULLY MET", 
"PARTIALLY MET"), BLOCK = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    TOTAL = c(12L, 27L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 28L, 27L, 13L, 25L, 30L, 
    15L, 23L, 13L, 11L, 24L, 8L, 23L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 21L, 
    28L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```